# How to measure convergence of data?

Tags: python, convergence

I am running a word-game simulations that assign values to words. In short, a computer is self-playing games of Scrabble and each move is recorded as (word, point value of the word). One value usually lies in (1,50) range, is always non-negative, but in extreme cases can reach 150-200 (sorry, I haven't calculated the distribution, but it is an interesting question in itself). After playing many games, we can determine the cumulative value of words, i.e. the more often the word was played, the more valuable it is. The list is sorted by values:

```
DZET,10938
SŁAŃ,10926
ZSADŹ,10925
BZYG,10925
ĆELĘ,10924
LWY,10910
ONĄ,10909
PAN,10906
NIW,10903
WÓŁ,10886
DNI,10882
GÓR,10878
ZWĘ,10877
```

Sample results after 1, 2 and 3 iterations: [1](http://pastebin.com/fATFC94J), [2](http://pastebin.com/49aVC2Hn), and [3](http://pastebin.com/wWHYUsXM). Real files are ~1e6 lines long and 50k games are played in between them, so the average increment per game is ~1 point for top words. For low-ranked words it will be much smaller. The convergence is reached when the ranking doesn't change any more, i.e. when we determined the best-valued words.

**Can you recommend a good way to measure convergence of these lists?** I would like to know how many iterations is enough for the words to stay on their positions. The points don't matter, only the position of a word on the list (their rank).

I can think of a very simple measure: for n in (number of iterations), take the differences between ranks in (n) and (n+1), and sum them. My knowledge of statistics is too sparse to tell whether it is a proper way though. For the top words, the difference will quickly become 0, but the further we are down the list, the longer it takes to converge (this is my assumption which I would like to confirm).

The question is tool-independent, but FYI I'll be using python pandas to do this.

Comment: You want them to converge to what? What are the numbers? Generally, the common approach to similar problems is to check if after subsequent iterations the values does not change more then some $\epsilon$ value. You however have to set the $\epsilon$ in some way. Knowing more about your algorithm and the data would help us to understand your problem.

Comment: @Tim, I elaborated a bit on the data. Since I don't know how exactly the data change with iterations, I guess $\epsilon$ is something I would like to find out.

Comment: But we don't know your algorithm, don't know what your algorithm does, and what are the numbers and how do they change. There is *no* general statistical test that says that some number is objectively "small" because sometimes small is $10^{-10}$ and sometimes "small" is $999.741$ depending on your data. You can always use some a priori criterion e.g. "it does not change more then 2x previous value" but to recommend something more sophisticated you should provide us more information.

Comment: @Tim, sorry, I am willing to share the details but if I haven't written enough it is just because I had not asked myself the questions that you are asking. I added more details about the numbers, is that better now?

Comment: I think the information that is lacking is *what* are the numbers? What do they mean?

Comment: @Tim, In word games, you usually get points for the words that you play. That is what I meant by (word, value) but now changed to (word, point value of the word). If you know how to make it clearer, please go ahead and change it.

Comment: So how do you define convergence? The situation in which you cannot get more points? It is not clear.

Comment: @Tim, the situation when you found the respective positions of words on the ranked list and they don't change any more.